# I want to add an add to favourite option in my android app

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am having simple wallpapers app in making. I Want add to favourite option to be implemented. i am using sqlite for storing links of images and then loding it through picasso. Help me out on how i can add favourite button working. Thank You!

Comment: Hello @ Mitesh if you got solution with my ans then you will right tick with my ans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add new column in your **Table**

for example **isFavourite**

and store **boolean**  value like 0 -unfavorite and 1 - favourite

then after you need to fire query how you want to get data from database

for more help you may refer [this link](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

**Example :**
We have this table - **DataTable**

[image]

1)  Writing SQLite Database Handler Class

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dataManager";

//  table name
private static final String TABLE_DATA = "data";

//  Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_IMG_URL = "ImgFavourite";
private static final String KEY_IS_FAVOURITE= "IsFavourite";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DATA + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_IMG_URL+ " TEXT,"
            + KEY_IS_FAVOURITE+ " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DATA );

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

**Inserting new Record**

```
// Adding new data
public void addData(Data data) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_IMG_URL, data.getImgUrl());
    values.put(KEY_IS_FAVOURITE, data.getIsFavoutire());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_DATA, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
```

**Updating Record**

```
// Updating single data
public int updateData(Data data) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_IMG_URL, data.getImgUrl());
    values.put(KEY_IS_FAVOURITE, data.getIsFavoutire());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_DATA, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(data.getID()) });
}
```

Note: SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

For more help need to refer [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: Ok. But how to save the sate of that favourite button

Comment: @Mitesh Parekh  - "save the sate of that favourite button" means?

you need to store boolean value like 0 -unfavorite and 1 - favourite  


if unclear please explain your question bro

Comment: For example  if user clicks on favourite button; button changes to red say and that item is added to favourite. but when user opens app again then that favourite button should be red indicating that item is in fav list so how to save that button state..

Comment: First of all you need to fire  save/update (insert/update) query to store favourite

You have to check it every time with query

For example

Select isFavourite from TableName where Id = 1;

You get is state which you stored

Comment: can you provide any code example please. As i am new to this @Adilhusen

Comment: what is getImgUrl()  method and getIsFavoutire() method

Comment: for more help you may refer this link ,you wil understand....its a model class methods which we pass data from our screen